# How can I handle keyboard behaviour and focus issue when using Accompanist WebView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I clear focus and hide keyboard using this.

```
Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(onTap = {
                localFocusManager.clearFocus()
            })
```

However, this only works with Composable Functions such as TextField.

I'd like to show the keyboard under the  so that the user can see the input field and he/she knows what's being typed. And also, when he/she touch outside of the  field, I'd like to hide the keyboard and clear the focus of .

How can I achieve this issue?